# Data driven Jestjs tests

Tags: jestjs

Is there a way to write more data driven tests with Jestjs?

I came up with something like this:

```
    it('assignments and declarations', () => {

    testCases.forEach(function (testCase) {
        const slx = fs.readFileSync(testDirectory + 'slx/' + testCase.slx, 'utf-8');

        const document = compiler.parse(slx);

        const lmsGenerator = new LMSGenerator(document);
        const lms = lmsGenerator.generate();

        const expected = fs.readFileSync(testDirectory + 'lms/' + testCase.lms, 'utf-8');

        expect(expected).toBe(lms);
    });
});
```

I read the input and the expected output out of files. The files (and the link between input and output) are saved in an array with objects. The problem is that I lost the specific errors messages I had with multiple it() functions.

Is there a way to do this better? Or to use an individual message for the case the expected-call will fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create an `it` block for every test case and bundle them in a `describe` block. Now you will get an error message for every broken case and the test will not stop after first failure.

```
describe('assignments and declarations for', () => {
  testCases.forEach(function (testCase) {
    it(`case ${testCase}`, () => {
      const slx = fs.readFileSync(testDirectory + 'slx/' + testCase.slx, 'utf-8');
      const document = compiler.parse(slx);
      const lmsGenerator = new LMSGenerator(document);
      const lms = lmsGenerator.generate();
      const expected = fs.readFileSync(testDirectory + 'lms/' + testCase.lms, 'utf-8');
      expect(expected).toBe(lms);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried that and got "Your test suite must contain at least one test." When I'm encapsulating the testCases.forEach call with a "fake" it block, the inner it block will never report an error to the encapsulating one.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with an example using jasmine: https://jsfiddle.net/3VuGs/402/. As jest use jasmine and I have done the same in my test jest test suite I have no idea why its not work for you. Can you add logs inside the `it` block to see if jest starts the tests.

Comment: Interesting that this is working for you. I cannot get it running in my environment. But I'm not sure if everything is configured correctly. At the moment I'm using WebStorm with a jest npm module. I'm starting the jest test run with a simple entry in the package.config:   "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",  }, Maybe that's the problem compared to your solution?